Trouble solving two simultaneous equations, $ab = \frac{1}{2}$ and $a^2 - b^2 = 0$
I am trying to solve the following simultaeneous equations:
$$ab =  \frac{1}{2}$$
$$a^2 - b^2 = 0$$
Expanding #2 gives us $(a+b)(a-b) = 0$, which in turn yields $a+b=0$ or $a-b=0$. Thus:
$$a=-b\text{ or }a=b$$
$$b=-a\text{ or }a=b$$
Substituting each of the above into $ab=\frac{1}{2}$: (note the $\pm$ square root for the last one, which gives 2 solutions)
$$(a,b) = (+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$$
$$(a,b) = (-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$$
$$(a,b) = (-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$$
$$(a,b) = (+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$$
Therefore, there are FOUR solutions.
HOWEVER:
I plotted the solutions on a graph:
graph
And there are only TWO intersection points, one at
$$(a,b) = (+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$$
and the other at
$$(a,b) = (-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$$
What happened?

If $a$ and $b$ have different signs, their product can't be positive.

Assuming $a,b$ are real, then if $a=-b$ or $b=-a$, then $ab$ cannot be $\frac 12$.

Your algebraic working seems to be wrong. From $a^2 - b^2 = 0$, you immediately saw that $a = ±b$. Now, we work out some cases.
CASE 1: $a = b$
The solutions are:
$$ab = a^2 = \dfrac{1}{2} \Longrightarrow \therefore a = b = ±\dfrac{\sqrt 2}{2}$$
which yields:
$$(a, b) = \left(\dfrac{\sqrt 2}{2}, \dfrac{\sqrt 2}{2}\right), \left(-\dfrac{\sqrt 2}{2}, -\dfrac{\sqrt 2}{2}\right)$$
CASE 2: $b = -a$
Your algebra should be:
$$a\cdot -a = -a^2 = \dfrac{1}{2} \Longrightarrow a^2 = -\dfrac{1}{2}$$
So, there are no solutions for $a, b \in \mathbb R$ in this case.
Therefore, we have a total of only two real solutions, which aligns with the graph.

Thanks a lot! I overlooked the $-\frac{1}{2}$, I thought the solution was real. That explains why I only saw 2 solutions on the graph; the others were supposed to be imaginary.

There are only 2 cases :
$a = b$ and
$a=-b $ ($ b = -a$ is the same as second one )
And since the product in second case $ab$ will be    $  -a^2 = 1/2 $ ( or $-b^2 = 1/2$ ) which gives imaginary solutions, the only real solutions are the ones shown in graph.

I will assume that you are working over the real numbers.
If $a=b$, then $ab=\frac12$ becomes $a^2=\frac12$. Then $a=\pm\frac1{\sqrt2}$, and therefore $(a,b)=\left(\frac1{\sqrt2},\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)$ or $(a,b)=\left(-\frac1{\sqrt2},-\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)$.
On the other hand, if $a=-b(\iff b=-a)$, then $ab=\frac12$ becomes $a^2=-\frac12$, which has no solutions.
So, yes, the only solutions are $\pm\left(\frac1{\sqrt2},\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)$.
